# How to loop a game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game and I need a set of poles to move from the right side of the screen to the left. once it gets to the left, I need to reset the poles to the beginning and go again in a continuous loop. Create poles simply sets the x position of both poles to the original starting position. The poles move just fine the problem is the looping aspect. I am not sure why the code below will not work. I am very new to swift and admit I am not too sure what I am doing.

```
  movePole()
    let create = SKAction.run {
        () in
        self.createPoles()
        self.movePole()
    }
    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10)
    let spawn = SKAction.sequence([create,delay])
    self.run(SKAction.repeatForever(spawn))
```

Comment: Can you please also add the code for movePole() ? As that is what your question is all about?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do:

1. Tell the poles to move a specific distance for a duration.
2. Tell the poles to move back to the start point.
3. Repeat.

As demonstrated here:

```
let AnimationTime = 5
let PoleTravelDistance = view.frame.width
let MovePolesToLeft = SKAction.move(by: CGVector(dx: PoleTravelDistance, dy: 0), duration: AnimationTime)
let ReturnPolesToRight = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: (POLESNODE.frame.width)/2, y: (POLESNODE.position.y)), duration: 0)
let PoleAnimationSequence = SKAction.sequence([MovePolesToLeft, ReturnPolesToRight])
POLESNODE.run(SKAction.repeatForever(PoleAnimationSequence))
```

Hope that helps.